# Azure AD Permissions Needed for Service Principal for Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

What are the Azure AD permissions needed for the 'App registration' that is used in an Azure DevOps (ADO) Service Principal to execute a IaC release pipeline that calls `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`?

I am trying to add access to the Key Vault for a `Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities`.

The error I see is:
"WARNING: Please make sure you have sufficient permissions in AD Graph to get and list graph objects for validation to work. Otherwise skip witch `-BypassObjectIdValidation`."

I have tried numerous combinations of AAD 'read' permissions. The current permissions I have reverted to are:
[image]

When I test locally using my personal login the script works fine, the access policy gets added, and the 'Managed Identity' is able to access the Key Vault secret. I have been able to use `-BypassObjectIdValidation` as a workaround in ADO but that seems like a hack. All of the Azure resources are in the same subscription and all objects are in the same Azure tenant, so it doesn't make sense to me that I should need to use the bypass switch.

**Additional Info:**

Digging into Microsoft's source, I'm further convinced the problem is within the service principal's AAD permissions. For example, the following code is calling into `Graph`.

```
if (!this.BypassObjectIdValidation.IsPresent && ActiveDirectoryClient != null)
{
    objId = GetObjectId(this.ObjectId, this.UserPrincipalName, this.EmailAddress, this.ServicePrincipalName);
}
else if (ActiveDirectoryClient == null && objId == null)
{
    throw new Exception(Resources.ActiveDirectoryClientNull);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/a31eaed8e1d4f52752222d138436ce975b05dd5f/src/KeyVault/KeyVault/Commands/SetAzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy.cs#L519

Continuing deeper:

```
adObjects = GraphClient.Objects.GetObjectsByObjectIds(new GetObjectsParameters { ObjectIds = objectIdBatch, IncludeDirectoryObjectReferences = true });
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/a31eaed8e1d4f52752222d138436ce975b05dd5f/src/Resources/Resources/ActiveDirectory/Models/ActiveDirectoryClient.cs#L280

Comment: Nice deep dive on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem is a 'known product limitation'.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10029#issuecomment-664485033

About a third of the way down in the help document:
[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-5.5.0#description

So it seems there is no combination of permissions that can set to enable the commandlet to work without the switch.

Comment: I would regrettably go with that as the answer. Regrettable in that they really should trust implementors to know what they're dealing with (provided the documentation is clear and up to date, of course)

Comment: @Stringfellow Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

It's an access control permission by RBAC role on the Key Vault.

Our setup gives the Azure DevOps service connection principal `Contributor` on the subscription, and that's sufficient. The docs verify, in fact that you should be careful who has `Contributor` on your Vaults, because they can give themselves access policies (where they normally can't in Azure).

If you want fewer privileges, I'd try `User Access Administrator` or `Key Vault Administrator.`

Comment: The service principal is a `Contributor` on the subscription. I have also tried adding the three different role assignments `Owner`, `Key Vault Administrator`, and `User Access Administrator`, without any success.